# Python How to finde the right value with soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the proce of an item from the following html.

This is the src

```html
<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="show-all-offers-display" data-show-all-offers-display="{}">
         <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/B08HLZXHZY/ref=dp_olp_NEW_mbc?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=NEW">
             <span>Neu (3) ab </span><span class="a-size-base a-color-price">1.930,99&nbsp;€</span>
         </a>
    </span>
    <span class="a-size-base a-color-base">&amp; <b>Kostenlose Lieferung</b></span>
</div>
```

This is the code that I tried

```
html = """\
HTML Code here from the top.
"""

soup = Soup(html)
soup.find("span", {"a-size-base a-color-price": ""}).text
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of issues in your code. See below:

```
html = """<div class="a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small">
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="show-all-offers-display" data-show-all-offers-display="{}">
<a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/offer-listing/B08HLZXHZY/ref=dp_olp_NEW_mbc?ie=UTF8&amp;condition=NEW">
<span>Neu (3) ab </span><span class="a-size-base a-color-price">1.930,99&nbsp;€</span>
</a>
</span>
<span class="a-size-base a-color-base">&amp; <b>Kostenlose Lieferung</b></span>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find("span", {"class":"a-size-base a-color-price"}).text.strip())
```

output

```
1.930,99 €
```